# Increasing the height of a specific font? -iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, size, barcode

I am creating an app in which the iphone generates barcodes from numbers and I have successfully generated the barcodes like I wanted. However, I want the barcode to be taller than it is. Is there any way to increase the height of the barcode font or any font for that matter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just set the font in the text field where the bar code is?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I am able to change the size of the font but I need to change only the height of the font.